# How to convert categorial data into indices with nan values present in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series, categorical-data

**Context**

I have created a function, that converts `Categorial Data` into its unique indices. This works great with all values except `NaN`.
It seems that the comparison with `NaN` does not work. This results in the two problems seen below.

---

**Code**

```py
   col1
0  male
1  female
2  NaN
3  female

def categorial(series: pandas.Series) -> pandas.Series:
    series = series.copy()

    for index, value in enumerate(series.unique()):
        # Problem 1: The output for the Value NaN is always 0.0 %, even though nan is present in the given series.
        print(index, value, round(series[series == value].count() / len(series) * 100, 2), '%')

    for index, value in enumerate(series.unique()):
        # Problem 2: Every unique Value is converted to its Index except NaN.
        series[series == value] = index

    return series.astype(pandas.Int64Dtype())
```

---

**Question**

- How can I solve the two problems seen in the code above?

Comment: Can you add some sample data to question?

Comment: @jezrael I added sample data to the question.

Comment: `nan` should be encoded some another way like another data? Like `pd.factorize(categorial(df['col1']))[0]` - nan is encoded to `-1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How should be encoded missing values `nan`s?

In pandas it is obviously `-1`:

```
print (pd.factorize(categorial(df['col1']))[0])
[ 0  1 -1  1]

print (df['col1'].astype('category').cat.codes)
0    1
1    0
2   -1
3    0
dtype: int8
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! `df['col1'].astype('category').cat.codes` solved the problem converting the categorial data. However, I can't figure out how to reproduce the printing part with your approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fillna` with `astype` and `factorize`:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna('nan').astype(str).factorize()[0]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b',np.nan,'c']})
print (df)
  col1
0    a
1    b
2  NaN
3    c

df['col1'] = df['col1'].fillna('nan').astype(str).factorize()[0]
print (df)
   col1
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3
```